# Python Matplotlib custom style error

Tags: python, matplotlib

i'm trying to use a custom matplotlib-style

But it does not work:

As mentioned here:

http://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html

i tried the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print plt.style.available
```

`matplotlib.pyplot` works fine. But it keeps saying that style is not defined.

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> print plt.style.available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'style'
```

What is the solution?

It is Mac Os X Yosemite and it is installed as Administrator in the default location.

Comment: go into your matplotlib folder in `site-packages` and check if the style folder exists. (the location of this depends on your operating system and Python installation)

Comment: i looked in the directory where "matplotlib.__file__" points to and there is no style folder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Styles* are a very recent feature of `matplotlib`, introduced in version 1.4.

- If your version of matplotlib is up-to-date then you are suffering
  from a bug of the installation procedure
- If your version is older than 1.4 then it is not expected that you
  have style sheets installed.

To look at your version, do the following (my `matplotlib` is old...)

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'1.3.1'
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you see

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'1.3.1'
>>>
```

And than you should make 1.4.1 or up

do it

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade matplotlib
```

or

```
sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

after update ,you will see as like that

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'1.5.0'
```

Comment: if running the above gives you an error on OSX. try
sudo pip install matplotlib --upgrade --ignore-installed six